# Fetching records from MySQL using LIKE and %

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I have table called `mpi` which contains 23 columns. I have introduced the search field with button for every column where user can enter the query to fetch the records using query

```
query="select * from mpi where Genus ='"+genus+"'
```

Now I want to fetch records by giving keywords using `LIKE` `%%` but it is not working and not giving any records but if type type the full name it is working perfectly. Here is the code

```
String uname=request.getParameter("uname"); 
String full="%"+uname+"%";
dbconn=new DatabaseConnection();        
conn=dbconn.setConnection();

pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from mpi where Genus LIKE ?");
pstmt.setString(1, full);
res=pstmt.executeQuery
```

Could any one tell me where is the mistake and why I am not getting the records when I use half keyword like %keyword%.

Comment: Show us real code, that actually compiles.

Comment: Why is your select statement selecting from a different table to the one you describe wanting to get data from in the text of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works (apart from the missing parentheses) and the approach with a prepared statement is entirely correct.

However I have seen a couple of code pieces like that, and always the problem lay with variables mix-up or not closing, or simple oversight. Better declare as close as possible.

```
try (ResultSet res = pstmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (res.next()) {
        ..
    }
} // Automatically closes res.
```

Also handle the life-cycle of pstmt correctly, with closing.